# Prevent a new updated Infopath form changing old archived forms on Sharepoint

Tags: infopath

Currently on Sharepoint, I have thousands of forms that have been filled in using a template that is now redundant.

When I updated the redundant template, it attempted to transfer the content stored within the old form, to the new form.

This is problematic, as some of the fields that previously existed, do not exist anymore.

Essentially I would like historical forms to use the original template (i.e to not update when I change the template), and for future forms to use the new updated template.

I would like to keep the old forms on Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The data is stored as XML, so the form's template is used to display the XML in a readable format. This means that the XML from old forms will always be displayed using the current template. I think you'd have to have a new library going forward to keep the old forms in their original format.